# Powershell KeyPress Modifiers

Tags: powershell

```
$Textbox.Add_Keydown({
  If ($Args[1].key -eq 'Shift' -and $Args[1].key -eq 'Return'){Function A}
  ElseIf ($Args[1].key -eq 'Return'){Function B}
})
```

I want to be able to make it do X on Shift+Enter and Y on just Enter. It should be very simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

I've attempted +Return, + Return, Shift Return, Return, +Enter...Anything I could think of.

Even,

```
If ($Args[1].key -eq 'Shift'){if($Args[1].key -eq 'Return'){Write-host "Working"}}
```

Is there some sort of keycode that I could use to represent Shift + Enter keys?

Comment: Why are you asking the [same question](http://superuser.com/questions/1069571/powershell-keydown-shiftenter) again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell keydown Shift+Enter](http://superuser.com/questions/1069571/powershell-keydown-shiftenter)

Comment: I voted to close the other as a duplicate of this one, since this one is better IMO (question-wise -- formatting, more concise, what was tried etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [KeyEventArgs Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx) (that's the type of argument you're dealing with here).

You can use the [KeyCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode.aspx) and [Shift](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.shift.aspx) properties to detect which keys are pushed, and if they're shifted.  E.g.:

```
$Textbox.Add_Keydown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter" -and $_.Shift) {
        Write-host "Working"
    }
})
```